# How to access Kitematic host computer's command line

Tags: mac, command-line, virtualbox, docker

I installed [Kitematic](https://kitematic.com/) to my Mac. Kitematic installs a Linux server to VirtualBox to work as a Docker host and has a simple GUI for the basic Docker tasks etc.

Now I'm wondering, how to have command line access to the Docker host (the Linux server running in VirtualBox)?

Comment: I'd like to have used "kitematic" tag but it's not available and I don't have enough reputation here to create a tag. Feel free to add the tag if you feel it would be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

With some googling and reading the docs a bit more, I found out that Kitematic installs also [docker-machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/) CLI tool that has ssh subcommand for this:

```
docker-machine ssh
```

(will use active machine as default). With multiple machines, one can specify the machine-name after ssh: `docker-machine ssh dev`